# Cassandra spawning too many instances, making server unavailable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load, cassandra, vps

I am having one huge problem recently. When I reboot server, it starts waaay to slow, it was relatively fast in the past. If I manage to log in to the terminal, I get the following screen: http://pokit.org/get/img/6412672ae48f9831a795db7b23eeb8d3.jpg

In the past there was a couple of these, now dozens, clogging up the list. The CPU usage, for the first one, goes to 300.-500.-800.% of CPU (in the column), and all of the 8 cores were like utilized 100% at that time. That stops after 5-10 minutes.

What might be causing this? I haven't touched these settings at all, related to cassandra, so I am really puzzled by what could've caused it to behave like this. Also, the RAM is pretty high, it was always around 1GB in the past, with a bit of swap.

EDIT: Log from cassandra output.log, last 200 lines: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=chuGusBh

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your logs?

Comment: logs seem to be normal.Is there any zombie process running in your system? Don't think it is a cassandra related issue

Comment: Well, I also thing the cassandra is not exactly causing this, but something is spawning so many instances so I wondered maybe is there some way to "see" whats launching and using it. I am experimenting with reddit's code, and it was all OK before, but now it spams dozens of instances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the cassandra seems to work this way as usual, server is now behaving nicely.